# How can I call the Android Rect function from Lua?

Tags: lua, luajava

```
uri = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&origin=50.291793,30.355700&destination=50.400024,30.623489"
local Intent = luajava.newInstance("android.content.Intent")
local Uri = luajava.bindClass("android.net.Uri")

Intent:setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
Intent:setData(Uri:parse(uri))

Intent:addFlags(bit32.bor(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK))

bundle = Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)

activity:startActivity(Intent, bundle)`
```

I need to call [`Rect`][1] to define bundle for multi window mode in Android.
This code is incorrect: `bundle = Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)` - the `Rect` function does not exist in Lua.

How can I do that?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect

Comment: Why is `bundle = Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)` incorrect?

Comment: There is no Rect() function in Lua.

Comment: Which `Rect` function are you trying to call then?

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect

Comment: Can you not also use something like `local Rect = luajava.bindClass("android.graphics.Rect")`?

Comment: There is NO Rect in luajava.bindClass("android.graphics.Rect") or I do not know how and what to call it

Comment: Never done it before, but google points me to using ```newInstance``` instead of ```bindClass```. like ```bundle = luajava.newInstance("android.graphics.Rect",0,0,200,200)```